# How to include (import) an istalled library (MPI) in my C compiler code?

Tags: c, mpi

I have to use the MPI library in my C compiler to execute the following code. I have installed the library but I don't know how to import it to use it. I am using Cygwin64. Can anyone please help?

This code is just a test.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 // Initialize the MPI environment
 MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

// Get the number of processes
int world_size;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

// Get the rank of the process
int world_rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

// Get the name of the processor
char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
int name_len;
MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

// Print off a hello world message
printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d out of %d processors\n",
       processor_name, world_rank, world_size);

// Finalize the MPI environment.
MPI_Finalize();
 }
```

Comment: Try adding something like `-lmpi` to your C compiler arguments to link the library with your code.

Comment: Better use `mpicc` instead of `gcc`

Answer (score 0):

[MPICH - FAQ](https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Q:_Why_can.27t_I_build_MPICH_on_Windows_anymore.3F) wrote:

> Q: Why can't I build MPICH on Windows anymore?
>   Unfortunately, due to the lack of developer resources, MPICH is not supported on Windows anymore including Cygwin. The last version of MPICH, which was supported on Windows, was MPICH2 1.4.1p1. There is minimal support left for this version, but you can find it on the downloads page:
>
> http://www.mpich.org/downloads/
>
> Alternatively, Microsoft maintains a derivative of MPICH which should provide the features you need. You also find a link to that on the downloads page above. That version is much more likely to work on your system and will continue to be updated in the future. We recommend all Windows users migrate to using MS-MPI.

Since there is no reference left of "MPICH2 1.4.1p1" on www.pich.org i'd suggest you use [MS-MPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/message-passing-interface/microsoft-mpi).

Comment: Mate, I have already installed an old version of it, just need the way of importing it and using it in my code.

Comment: @Ali would help to know what exactly you downloaded.

Comment: Open MPI is a Cygwin package (but cannot be built under *native* windows.